# Button is not working in HTML which is manipulated by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a new JavaScript learner and I love gaming. So, I have decided to make a voting website which will take votes from visitors to watch their favourite game wins. I have codded like this.

The very first thing is the HTML part:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Vote For FPS GAMES</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <script src="vendor.js" defer></script>
 <script src="app.js" defer></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="card1">
    <div class="card-image"></div>

    <div class="card-text">
    <span class="date">VOTE FOR COD</span>
    <h2>GAME-1</h2>
    <p>COD is mainly known as CALL OF DUTY. </p>
    </div>

    <div class="buttonadding">
        <button id="vote-btn-cod"> VOTE FOR COD</button>
    </div>

    <div class="card-stats">
        <div class="stat">
            <div id="stats-value-cod" class="value" value="0" >0</div>
            <div class="type">popularity</div>
        </div>
        <div class="stat">
            <div class="value">2123</div>
            <div class="type">views</div>
        </div>
        <div class="stat">
            <div class="value">0</div>
            <div class="type">comments</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="card2">
    <div class="card2-image"></div>

    <div class="card2-text">
    <span class="date">VOTE FOR APEX-LEGENDS</span>
    <h2>GAME-2</h2>
    <p>APEX LEGENDS IS A PRODUCT OF EA-SPORTS </p>
    </div>

    <div class="buttonadding">
        <button id="vote-btn-Apex"> VOTE FOR APEX-LEGENDS</button>
    </div>

    <div class="card2-stats">
        <div class="stat">
            <div class="value" id="stats-value-apex">0</div>
            <div class="type">popularity</div>
        </div>
        <div class="stat">
            <div class="value">0</div>
            <div class="type">views</div>
        </div>
        <div class="stat">
            <div class="value">32</div>
            <div class="type">comments</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="card3">
    <div class="card3-image"></div>

    <div class="card3-text">
    <span class="date">VOTE FOR PUBG</span>
    <h2>GAME-3</h2>
    <p>PUBG IS A PRODUCT X-BOX </p>
    </div>
    <div class="buttonadding">
        <button id="vote-btn-pubg"> VOTE FOR PUBG</button>
    </div>
    <div class="card3-stats">
        <div class="stat">
            <div class="value" id="stats-value-pubg">0</div>
            <div class="type">popularity</div>
        </div>
        <div class="stat">
            <div class="value">0</div>
            <div class="type">views</div>
        </div>
        <div class="stat">
            <div class="value">32</div>
            <div class="type">comments</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have divided the JavaScript into two files:

1. vendor.js
2. app.js

here are those:

vendor.js

```
const voteforcod = document.getElementById('vote-btn-cod');
const voteforapex = document.getElementById('vote-btn-Apex');
const voteforpubg = document.getElementById('vote-btn-pubg');

const popcod = document.getElementById('stats-value-cod');
const popapex = document.getElementById('stats-value-apex');
const poppubg = document.getElementById('stats-value-pubg');
```

and app.js

```
let increcod=0;
let increapex=0;
let increpubg=0;
function addpopcod() {
    alert("button clickd");
    popcod.value = popcod.value+1;
    console.log(String(popcod.value)); 
}

function addpopapex() {
    popapex.value++;
}

function addpoppubg() {
    poppubg.value++;
}

voteforcod.addEventListener('click',addpopcod);
voteforapex.addEventListener('click',addpopapex);
voteforpubg.addEventListener('click',addpoppubg);
```

Whenever I call the function addpopcod, it should give an alert that the button has been clicked, but nothing happens. Please help me sort this. Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the console?

Comment: Your code is fine, at least to see the alert; for the counter, you'll need `parseInt(popcod.value) + 1` so the value is converted from string to integer.

Comment: Your code works if you put the scripts at the end of the body. It appears to be a load order issue.

Comment: Your code is running fine for me. 
https://jsfiddle.net/2nb716p4/

Maybe you forgot to wait for loading document to load?

Comment: @Triby Thanks a lot. I have forgotten to use live server as the frequent change didn't notify me. And I have another thing to know..Would you please help me? If I clicked the vote button, then it should increment the value and show me how many of the visitor will press the vote button for that particular game? I have used innerHTML, but it seems, there is no change...

Comment: @Marco , Thanks for your precious time...

Comment: Thanks everyone..I have done it by this :                             
    popcod.value = popcod.value+1;
    popcod.innerHTML=popcod.value;